# How to mask a tomcat app behind an apache subdomain?

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I have two separate servers: an Apache public server and an internal Tomcat one. I would like our users to be able to use our Tomcat apps without exposing the details of our implementation (actual port, server name, context) through the public Apache server like this:

`http://credits.publicdomain.com/servlet`

instead of

`http://tomcat.internaldomain.com:8082/CreditsApp/servlet`

How can I configure my Apache server to mask requests to our Tomcat apps this way? Is using Apache modules such as mod_rewrite or mod_proxy the most straightforward approach?

I have tried this configuration for a VirtualHost in Apache, which works for the first servlet. However it seems to disable Tomcat to keep the session from the first servlet to any other servlet you go afterwards:

`ServerName credits.publicdomain.com`

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>                        

ProxyPass        / http://tomcat.internaldomain.com:8082/CreditsApp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://tomcat.internaldomain.com:8082/CreditsApp/
```

Am I missing some additional configuration in my Tomcat server in order to work without the context between servlets?

Comment: Q: Is using Apache modules such as mod_rewrite or mod_proxy the most straightforward approach?  A: Yes :)  These links might be useful: http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies and [Using Apache2 as a Reverse Proxy](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/reqpro/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.reqpro.install_upgrade.doc/topics/rw_apache.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best and most efficient way to do this is using mod_jk: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/

I've used this in several projects and found it to be extremely easy to use, effective, flexible, and performant. It's also the de facto official solution to stacking Tomcat behind Apache.

Answer (score 1):

**mod_jk** is what you need to bridge Tomcat to Apache, so you can focus on your app
and Apache, as the front-end, can deal with https and authentication and such. It will forward certain URLs to 'workers' in Tomcat. So you need to tell Apache to load the mod_jk, you need to configure worker.properties, Apache would need to know which worker does what, and you need to define a Service in Tomcat.

**These directives in httpd.conf configure mod_jk:**

JKWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JKLogFile       /var/log/tomcat/mod_jk.log
JKLogLevel      info

The JKWorkersFile in /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties basically defines sockets

```
 workers.tomcat_home=/var/tomcat4
 workers.java_home=/usr/java/jdk
 ps=/
 worker.list=worker1,worker2
 worker.worker1.port=8009
 worker.worker1.host=localhost
 worker.worker1.type=ajp13
 worker.worker2.port=8010
 worker.worker2.host=localhost
 worker.worker2.type=ajp13
```

**This snippet for httpd.conf would delegate everything (i.e. /* ) to worker1:**

```
<VirtualHost 192.0.34.72>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@ example.com
      DocumentRoot /www/www.example.com/webapps/ROOT
      ServerName www.example.com
      ErrorLog logs/public_errors
      LogLevel debug
      CustomLog logs/public_access combined
      JkMount /* worker1
      <Directory "/www/www. example.com/webapps/ROOT">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Indexes
          AllowOverride None
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
     </Directory>
      <Location "/WEB-INF/">
          AllowOverride None
          deny from all
      </Location>
      <Location "/META-INF/">
          AllowOverride None
          deny from all
      </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**And Tomcat would have this service:**

```
<service name="public">
    <connector classname="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteConnector" port="8009" minprocessors="5" maxprocessors="75" enablelookups="true" redirectport="8443" acceptcount="10" debug="0" connectiontimeout="0" useurivalidationhack="false" protocolhandlerclassname="org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler" /> 
    <engine name="Standalone" defaulthost="localhost" debug="0">
        <logger classname="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" prefix="catalina_log." suffix=".txt" timestamp="true" /> <realm classname="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" debug="0" resourcename="UserDatabase" /> ￼￼￼ 
        <host name="localhost" debug="0" appbase="/www/www.example.com/webapps" unpackwars="true" autodeploy="true">
            <logger classname="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_log." suffix=".txt" timestamp="true" /> 
        </host>
    </engine>
</service>
```

The above examples are from my notes, check update documentation at:
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/workers.html
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html